# How I can display in nginx 80 data of another port website on the same server?

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

I have this:

```
location /cloud/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
```

but I can't see in browser in url http://someipaddress/cloud/ content of http://someipaddress:8000, why? someipaddress:8000 - works well. I also can do wget of localhost:8000 and it works.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the full NGINX config for this location (whole server block)

Answer (score 0):

You want to see the content of http://123.123.123.123:8000/ whenever you point your browser to http://123.123.123.123/somepath/.

A quick solution would be to create a file "index.html" inside the "somepath" folder with an iframe occupying the whole browser viewport:

```
<html>
  <title>Redirecting</title>
  <body>
  <iframe src="http://123.123.123.123:8000/" width="100%" height="100%" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px;"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is u have two urls

http://someipaddress/cloud/
and
http://someipaddress:8000

As per ur example. However if u see the domain name is the same. This makes it in my opinion a infinte loop.

if u have to use the same domain name then try rewrite maybe it will work for you.